# How to write own code to replace `std::min_element` to find smallest value in vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stdvector

I try to find the smallest value in a `std::vector` container.

I know `std::min_element` works fine. But I am coding for a stm32 chip, that supports `c++11`. However, the cross compiler has some issues with `<algorithm>` header.

I want a clear and effect way to do that.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: What about the possible implementations in this [reference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element), have you already tried?

Answer (score 1):

Generic `std::min_element` implementation might look like this. It returns iterator to minimum and `end` for empty range and supports custom comparator function.

```
template
<
    typename ForwardIt,
    typename Cmp = std::less<typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIt>::value_type>
>
ForwardIt min_element(ForwardIt begin, ForwardIt end, Cmp cmp = Cmp{})
{
    if (begin == end)
        return end;
    ForwardIt min = begin++;
    for (; begin != end; ++begin)
        if (cmp(*begin, *min))
            min = begin;
    return min;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
std::vector<int> myVector = /* ... */;
int min = myVector[0];
for (auto itr = myVector.cbegin (); itr != myVector.cend (); itr ++)
  {
    if (*itr < min)
      min = *itr;
  }
```

`min` now contains the smallest value

Simple, effective, working. Iterators are a strength of C++.